# Login Form Not POSTing Correctly

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm developing a login form with react-native. My back-end definitely works, but I have included it below for reference (I've tested this by using a curl command). Anyway, I'm trying to figure out why this react-native login form doesn't POST on form submission. Whenever I attempt to debug by simply adding an `alert("test")` it seems to call `_handleSubmit()` whenever there is a detected change in either of the FormInputs. Below is the react-native code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { FormInput } from 'react-native-elements';
import {Animated, View, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import cssta from "cssta/native";
import Config from 'react-native-config';


const LoginButtonContainer = cssta(Animated.View)`
  --primary: white;
  --foreground: var(--primary);
  --background: #1b2535;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: var(--background);
`;

const LoginButtonText = cssta(Animated.Text)`
  color: var(--foreground);
  text-align: center;
`;

const RegisterButtonContainer = cssta(Animated.View)`
  --primary: #1b2535;
  --foreground: var(--primary);
  --background: white;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid var(--primary);
  background-color: var(--background);
`;

const RegisterButtonText = cssta(Animated.Text)`
  color: var(--foreground);
  text-align: center;
`;


export default class Login extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            username: '',
            password: ''
        };
    }

    _handleSubmit() {
        let username = this.state.username;
        let password = this.state.password;

        fetch('http://localhost:4200/login', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
        }).then((response) => JSON.stringify(response.json()))
            .then((responseData) => { console.log("response: " + responseData); })
            .catch((err) => { console.log(err); });
    }

    _onRegisterClick() {

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <View style={{justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                <FormInput
                    placeholder='Username'
                    onChangeText={(username) => this.setState({username})}
                    value={this.state.username}
                />
                <FormInput
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onChangeText={(password) => this.setState({password})}
                    value={this.state.password}
                />
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleSubmit()}>
                    <LoginButtonContainer>
                        <LoginButtonText>Login</LoginButtonText>
                    </LoginButtonContainer>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onRegisterClick()}>
                    <RegisterButtonContainer>
                        <RegisterButtonText>Register</RegisterButtonText>
                    </RegisterButtonContainer>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
};
```

The next bit of code is a snippet of my back-end code

```
import models from './models';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
const express = require('express');
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
const app = express();

app.use('/', express.Router());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const PORT = 4200;

app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.username);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running at PORT ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Press Function accepts a function as an arguments. But in your code rahter then passing a function you are invoking the funtion.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleSubmit()}>
```

Change To

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=> this._handleSubmit()}>
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Try This code**

```
  let _username = this.state.username;
  let _password = this.state.password;

  let params = {
    username: _username,
    password: _password
  };

  var formBody = [];
  for (var property in params) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(params[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
  }
  formBody = formBody.join("&");

  let fetchData = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: formBody
  };

  fetch("http://localhost:4200/login", fetchData)
    .then(response => JSON.stringify(response.json()))
    .then(responseData => {
      console.log("response: " + responseData);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
```